# All products are sold out while Stock Status index is processing

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, stock, indexing, ee-1.11

Is this behaviour normal?

All the products are appearing as beeing sold out, and when I checked in Index Managemenet Stock Status shows as 'processing'. 
This didn't happened before.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, Your indexer run when a product is stock out or you change inventory, even on an product update, it still in processing till he index properly.

If `processing` stay for long time then you can refresh your indexer with SSH or try one to reindex manually from admin panel.